# Visual Studio 2008 is not stopping at all my break points and often “runs away” when I step over a statement, why?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I find often that **breakpoint** on line of code I know are executing do not break correctly.
It also often “**runs away**” when I do a “**step over**”, or “**step into**” etc.

**Details.**

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1
- The code is a mixture of VB.NET and C# with most of the code in VB.NET.
- There are a lot of active threads
- A lot of exceptions are throw and caught by the software.
- Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Standard Edition

Some other people on the team have seen this problem at different  times, but on one know how they fixed it!

---

Update, thinks for all the useful answers they will help other peole that hit this problem.

Hot fix [KB957912](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1796) - [Updates for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 debugging and breakpoints](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912)

> Microsoft has released updates for
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1
>   debugger components. These updates
>   mostly address issues that occur with
>   stepping and with hitting breakpoints.

This seems to have sorted the problmes out for me.

Comment: I get this a occasionally when debugging WinForms apps, haven't ever managed to fix it permanently. I never see this problem when debugging ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hot fix [KB957912](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1796) - [Updates for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 debugging and breakpoints](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912)

> Microsoft has released updates for
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1
>   debugger components. These updates
>   mostly address issues that occur with
>   stepping and with hitting breakpoints.

This seems to have sorted the problmes out for me.

Answer (score 4):

Few things:

1. First clean the solution using the "clean solution".
2. Run the program in debug mode
3. Remove all the breakpoints and put a breakpoint where you intend to check.
4. If its multithread, you might get a breakpoint stop at some time or may get delayed because of breakpoints at other parts of the code.
5. Ensure your code is reachable where you put a breakpoint. Code below may not every raise a breakpoint break in the else block,

   if(true)

   printf("Hello world");

   else

   printf("no hello world");

You would see the code never reached else part of no hello world.

This may sound funny. But closing the solution and visual studio and deleting directoris like release/debug and restarting system may do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a stupid question and it's fairly unlikely as it sounds like your behaviour is intermittent, but I've not seen anyone else ask it - have you checked to make sure you don't have any of the procedures with `System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough` attribute set on them?

Comment: Thats not the problem, as the debuger would just stop on the line after the call.  Also we don't have DebuggerStepThrough on most of our code.

Answer (score 1):

Most often that is because your code is optimized away. You need a debug build to ensure that the generated executables remain the same line for line at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, this is not my problem I have check that everywere I am trying to break into is build for debug

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your code and pdb files are in sync.  You may need to clean/rebuild the solution if this is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of threads, then this can happen - because multiple threads will trigger different breakpoints. So keep the thread window open to see if you're still on the same thread. Also timestamped tracing/logging might be a better option in this scenario than stepping through code in a multi-threaded app.

The other scenario where this can happen is that the binaries and pdb's don't match. So go for a full rebuild with optimizations turned off.
HTH

Comment: I am not getting a different breakpoint hit, so I don't think it is due to breaks point being hit in another thread

Answer (score 0):

This Will happen if you are using threads

if you aren't,try to rebuild your application